# Error building wrapper around Rcpp function

Tags: r, rcpp

I have the following function declared in `Rcpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <Rmath.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double loglikZeta(double zold, double zstar, NumericVector y, int K, double p){
NumericVector num = Rcpp::dbinom(y,K,p*zstar);
NumericVector den = Rcpp::dbinom(y,K,p*zold);
return (num[0]/den[0]);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double singleZetaSampler(NumericVector z, NumericVector y,
                     double p, int K, int i, double zstar){

return loglikZeta(z[i-1],zstar,y[i-1],K,p);
}
```

Now declare (after having loaded package and file):

```
z <- y <- c(rep(1,20),rep(0,20))
n <- length(y)
K <- 3
p <- 0.5
i <- 30
zstar <- 1
```

The unexpected behaviour is that if I try to call I have everytime different results (there is nothing random in the function):

```
singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
[1] 1.000051
singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
[1] 0.1887447
singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
[1] 0.9999998
```

Is there any big error am I doing here or these results are actually unexpected?

EDIT:

Sorry if the function doesn't make sense used as it is. This was the original function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector zetaSampler(int n, NumericVector z, NumericVector y,
                      double p, int K){
NumericVector xx(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    xx(i) = loglikZeta(z[i],1,y[i],K,p);

}

return xx;
}
```

and calling:

```
zetaSampler(length(z),z,y,p,K)
```

as before gives different results every time.

Answer (score 2):

Two things. One actual error, one sort-of-stylistic.

The stylistic issue is that you include `Rmath.h` and depend on RcppArmadillo when you should not.  The real error is that you sample 20 times but then set `i=30` and access the 30th element.  So you get random inputs.

Here is what I just ran, and it gets three times the same result.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double loglikZeta(double zold, double zstar, NumericVector y, int K, double p){
  NumericVector num = Rcpp::dbinom(y,K,p*zstar);
  NumericVector den = Rcpp::dbinom(y,K,p*zold);
  return (num[0]/den[0]);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double singleZetaSampler(NumericVector z, NumericVector y,
                         double p, int K, int i, double zstar){

  return loglikZeta(z[i-1],zstar,y[i-1],K,p);
} 

/*** R
z <- y <- c(rep(1,20),rep(0,20))
n <- length(y)
K <- 3
p <- 0.5
i <- 20  # not 30
zstar <- 1
singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
*/
```

Output:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/foo.cpp")

R> z <- y <- c(rep(1,20),rep(0,20))

R> n <- length(y)

R> K <- 3

R> p <- 0.5

R> i <- 20  # not 30

R> zstar <- 1

R> singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
[1] 1

R> singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
[1] 1

R> singleZetaSampler(z,y,p,K,i,zstar)
[1] 1
R>
```

*Edit:* Appears to work better in a repaired version forcing scalar arguments to `loglikZeta()`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double loglikZeta(double zold, double zstar, double y, int K, double p){
  double num = R::dbinom(y, K, p*zstar, false);
  double den = R::dbinom(y, K, p*zold, false);
  return (num/den);
}
```

Note that `Rcpp::dbinom()` has a signature of `Rcpp::dbinom(Rcpp::NumericVector, int, double, bool=false)`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why I should not set `i=30`

Comment: My mistake. Was in a rush getting out of the office. Vector is indeed of length 40.  Do not understand why you get different results.

Comment: Don't worry, thank you anyway. I just hope it's not a bug

Comment: There are a lot of things which make no sense and which you should study carefully.  You pass / access a few NumericVectors, yet seem to treat everything as scalars.  None of that should make a difference but I suspect that an errors lurks somewhere.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel directly accessing Rmath via the `R::` scope and dropping the `NumericVector` context resolved the issue in my initial test.

Comment: Same here but it doesn't explain the apparent "instability". OPs code is a little overly complicated (eg the loglik function), and hits `Rcpp::dbinom()` the wrong way but the outcome is still very strange.

Comment: I made an edit, apologize if the previous function didn't make sense but it was not easy to isolate the error from a more complex context. Some mistakes however are probably due to the fact that I just started using `rcpp` "seriously" :)